# Backspace not working properly for masked input textbox

Tags: jquery, html, mask

I am using jquery.mask.js for masking the textbox for mobile

Masking for canada zipcode 'A1A 1A1' was applied to textbox and it was working as expected, except the backspace or delete functionality.

After entering the input and trying to delete the specific letter was not working.

[image: Trying to delete the character 'a']

When i delete 'a' it also deletes the number '1'

```
HTML 

<label>Canada Zip Code: </label>
<input type="text" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" />

JQUERY

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#zipcode').mask("S0S 0S0");    
});
```

I know i can use some other plugin like ***jquery.maskedinput.js*** but when i use this am facing different issues so i want to stick with ***jquery.mask.js*** since its working fine in all mobiles except backspace functionality.

**JS fiddle :**
https://jsfiddle.net/qjtLbw44/1/

Comment: Is this issue still not resolved?

Comment: Yes :( It would be great if you provide any help on this